# Formateo de número

Tags: php, javascript, formato

El problema es el siguiente ej :

En una caja de texto escribo q cuesta $625, él atumáticamente me tiene que poner una coma, o sea cuesta 6,25$ pero si  el producto cuesta  600$ no debería de colocarme coma alguna porque no tiene céntimos.

Pero puede costar  600,25$ ¿Cómo hago para que una caja de texto me reconozca eso?

Yo tengo este pero no se modificarlo:

```
function format(input)
{
  var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
  if(!isNaN(num)){
  num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
  num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
  input.value = num;
}


}
<label for="message-text" class="control-label">precio :</label>

 <input type="num" class="form-control" onKeyUp="format(input)" onchange="format(this)"  id="precio">
```

Answer (score 0):

Checa el modulo 100 de tu cantidad. Por ejemplo si es cero no colocas las comas si 600 %100  =0 entonces 600/100= 6 sino 625/100=6,25

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto , el valor cambia cuando quitas el foco del input

```js
   function format(input) {
        var val = input.value;
        if (val % 100 == 0) {

            val = val / 100;
        } else {
            val = val / 100;
        }
        input.value = val;
    }
```

```html
<label for="message-text" class="control-label">precio :</label>

<input type="num" class="form-control"  onchange="format(this)" id="precio">
```